# Kotlin/Native GTK Interop

Tags: c++, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, kotlin-interop

I have a [def file](https://github.com/Doomsdayrs/kotlinx-gtk/blob/6d23960c495e5b3fde982055977dc7c72aa60c1f/src/nativeInterop/cinterop/gtk.def)

File contents:

```
headers = gtk/gtk.h
package = gtk
headerFilter = gtk/* gobject/* gio/* gdk/* glib/* gdk-pixbuf/*

compilerOpts = -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0
linkerOpts = -lgtk -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

I'm currently stuck at an error of

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32:10: fatal error: 'glibconfig.h' file not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello! Are you sure this header is presented across those folders, and have exactly that name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74423238/kotlin-native-how-to-import-entire-gtk4-libs-and-headers-to-kotlin-native-c-in